# Why are these asp checkbox values not being passed to SQL?

Tags: asp-classic

The code seemed to be working earlier, and I am not sure if any changes were made or what, but now this is not working for saving the checkbox values. It has no problems retrieving the old saved values when the page loads, however. Can anyone see the reason why the values are not being inserted now?

Code for checkboxes:

```
<%if confirmationstatusarray(k) = True Then%>
<td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id = "confirmation(<%=k%>)" name="confirmation(<%=k%>)" value="Y" checked disabled>Confirmed<br></td>
<%end if%>
<%if confirmationstatusarray(k) <> True Then%>
<td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id = "confirmation(<%=k%>)" name="confirmation(<%=k%>)" value="Y">Confirm<br></td>
<%end if%>
```

Code to enter checkbox values into SQL table:

```
enteredby = Session("empno") 'session empno, used for empno & enteredby
  for i = 0 to clientrows
    selectedclientnos = Request.form("selectedclientnos(" & i & ")")
    confirmationcheck = Request.form("confirmation(" & i & ")")

    'set checkbox value in array to 0 if unchecked
    If confirmationcheck = "" Then
    confirmationcheck = "0"
    End If

    if ((confirmationcheck <> "0") and (confirmedby(i) = "")) then 'checks if client offset has not yet been confirmed, and if box has been checked, if so will save session empno
        strSQL = "update Incident_FinancialOffsets set confirmedby = '"&enteredby&"' where incidentid = "&incidentid&" AND cno = '"&selectedclientnos&"';"
        Set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)  
        confirmationcheck = 0
    end if
  next
```

Comment: I know this is unrelated to your question, but building your SQL statements like that makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. I strongly advise parameterizing those SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of the conditions for the SQL update was not being met. Checking if the string (confirmedby) is blank was not enough, so I also checked for IsEmpty(confirmedby(i)) and this fixed the issue.

```
confirmedby = confirmedby(i)

    if ((confirmationcheck <> "0") and ((IsEmpty(confirmedby) or (confirmedby = "")))) then 'checks if client offset has not yet been confirmed, and if box has been checked, if so will save session empno
        strSQL = "update Incident_FinancialOffsets set confirmedby = '"&enteredby&"' where incidentid = "&incidentid&" AND cno = '"&selectedclientnos&"';"
        Set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)  
        confirmationcheck = 0
    end if
```